# Gatsby.js css: custom properties

Tags: css, postcss, css-modules, gatsby, css-variables

I installed gatsby cli and created a basic node / gatsby.js project.
The tutorial says "*Gatsby works out of the box with CSS Modules.*"
I also wanted to use custom css properties as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables

(1) I created `src/layouts/variables.css` and put in css with custom properties, like:

```
:root {
    --brand-color: #ff3333;
}
```

(2) Then in `src/layouts/index.css` I added `@import './variables.css'` at the very top of the css file.

(3) because of the @import in the above step, I installed and added `postcss-import` as the first plugin, in my `gatsby-config.js` file. Not sure if this is correct, as it isn't named 'gatsby-plugin-*' like the other plugins.

(4) in my footer component (`src/components/Footer`) I have both index.js and index.module.css. In the `index.module.css` I put:

```
.footer {
  color: var(--brand-color);
}
```

... thinking that --brand-color will cascade via imports through src/variables.css -> src/index.css -> src/index.js -> layouts/index.js -> my footer component.

But when I run gatsby-develop, it says:

**warning  in ./src/components/Footer/index.module.css**

**postcss-custom-properties: /path/to/src/components/Footer/index.module.css:2:3: variable '--brand-color' is undefined and used without a fallback.**

How can I fix this error? It does not allow the website to display properly.

Answer (score 4):

OK I figured out what I was doing wrong:

Every (.module).css file that needs to use the "global" variables.css file must import it explicitly.

Adding `@import '../../layouts/variables.css';` to my component's css file fixed this.